# jquery remove plugin from element

Tags: jquery, plugins

I've got something similar to the following code:

```
$(a).click(function() {
  $(element).plugin();
});
```

Is there a way to remove a plugin from an element other than using `$($.plugin).remove()`? Not sure if I have the terminology correct but basically I want to reset the element to it's original state.

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that will completely depend on the plugin. Things like the jQuery UI dialog wrap all sorts of junk around your element and move it to a different place in the DOM, so an "undo" function would be pretty challenging.

Comment: ok, thanks! btw, had a quick gander at your blog http://whatthepointy.blogspot.com/ and said it can't be found...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'd have to know what the plugin does in order to reverse it's effects.  Many plugins add extra elements to the DOM, handlers to elements, etc.  If the plugin doesn't create any extra elements, you might be able to simply do a [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) (without data and events) and replace or even just [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) all event handlers, but that's not always going to be effective.  It would be very dependent on the plugin in question.

Comment: Yep, I think the general concensus is look at the plugin first. Cheers

Answer (score 25):

Here is my dirty solution:

```
$('#myWidget,#myWidget *').unbind().removeData();
```

Comment: Perfect solution! I was missing the removeData() function.

Comment: but also be aware that removeData() will remove `any` data attribute attached to the element. if you know what data props it is attaching, it is better practice to remove them instead.

Answer (score 5):

Unless the plugin provides that functionality, it probably can not be done that easily. You'll have to investigate what the plugin does, and specifically undo those things - or store a clone of the non-plugged-in element to replace it with later.