# How to completely remove a jQuery.prototype plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Let's say I have a plugin, for example:

```
(function (jQuery) {
    var somevars = 0;

    jQuery.fn.someFunc = function () {
      // do some work
    };

    jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {
      // do some initialization etc...
    }
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".someclass").myPlugin();
});
```

Now let's say I want to remove it completely with something like:

```
jQuery(".someclass").destroy("myPlugin");
```

How can I do that? **Completely remove the plugin from the object**, functions, data, events, everything.

**UPDATE**

Assume no method to destroy itself exist, assume you are using someone else plugin which self bind to few elements on the page when initialized, and assume after some interaction with the user you need to completely remove it with all its binding.

Is it possible? Or the only solution is to go through the code of the plugin and discover how to remove it and add some methods to remove it?

Comment: Not without knowing which data (functions, objects, event, event handlers, etc) is part of the plugin or the plugin providing such as method by itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205920/jquery-remove-plugin-from-element

Comment: I should have thought better, given how many things a plugin could be doing, changing the dom, binding events here and there, I agree it's a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Given how many things a plugin could be doing, changing the DOM, binding events here and there, there's no way to remove it and clean up with some magical command.