# IE7 conditional - remove script

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-statements

all I simply want to do is; if the browser is less than internet explorer 8 find and remove `$(document).foundation();`

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
   //code here
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply deleting a plugin like that, e.g.

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]><!-->
<script>
  delete $.fn.foundation;
</script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Will probably cause all sorts of problems and is generally a bad idea - [see here for why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205920/jquery-remove-plugin-from-element).

Instead, just load the `foundation()` plugin/related scripts if the browser is IE8+ or a different browser:

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]><!-->
<script src="/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
// Other related scripts etc...
<!--<![endif]-->
```