# Replacing hardcoded datetime with current datetime in Jquery Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am working on building a Countdown timer built in `Jquery` from http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Extremely-Lightweight-jQuery-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-downCount.html. The script has a hardcoded datetime. I would like to replace it with the current datetime. I can do with `new Date()`, but then the offset seems to have no impact so the countdown timer always alerts right away.

```
<script class="source" type="text/javascript">
        $('.countdown').downCount({
            date: '09/09/2016 12:00:00',
            offset: +10
        }, function () {
            alert('Time Up');
        });
</script>
```

with current datetime:

```
<script class="source" type="text/javascript">
        $('.countdown').downCount({
            date: new Date(),
            offset: +10
        }, function () {
            alert('Time Up');
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the date to the plugin as a string?:

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth()+1;
var year = date.getFullYear();
var hour = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var seconds = date.getSeconds();

var dateString = day + '/' + month + '/' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;

$('.countdown').downCount({
  date: dateString,
  offset: +10
}, function () {
  alert('Time Up');
});
```

```js
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth()+1;
var year = date.getFullYear();
var hour = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var seconds = date.getSeconds();

var dateString = day + '/' + month + '/' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;

$('.countdown').downCount({
  date: dateString,
  offset: +10
}, function () {
  alert('Time Up');
});
```

```css
ul.countdown {
list-style: none;
margin: 75px 0;
padding: 0;
display: block;
text-align: center;
}
ul.countdown li {
display: inline-block;
}
ul.countdown li span {
font-size: 80px;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 80px;
}
ul.countdown li.seperator {
font-size: 80px;
line-height: 70px;
vertical-align: top;
}
ul.countdown li p {
color: #a7abb1;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Extremely-Lightweight-jQuery-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-downCount/jquery.downCount.js"></script>

<ul class="countdown">
<li> <span class="days">00</span>
<p class="days_ref">days</p>
</li>
<li class="seperator">.</li>
<li> <span class="hours">00</span>
<p class="hours_ref">hours</p>
</li>
<li class="seperator">:</li>
<li> <span class="minutes">00</span>
<p class="minutes_ref">minutes</p>
</li>
<li class="seperator">:</li>
<li> <span class="seconds">00</span>
<p class="seconds_ref">seconds</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @I had realized it had to be a string, but it seems obvious now. Thanks. It is possible to have a button reset the timer?

Comment: @user2242044 - In theory, yes - but this plugin doesn't have a built-in "destroy" method, so you will have to make it yourself. Maybe this post can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205920/jquery-remove-plugin-from-element

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I took a look and tried to build something if you wouldn't mind taking a look....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707958/countdown-timer-with-reset-function-using-jquery-and-downcount