# Unbinding a Jquery plugin completely from DOM on viewport resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slick slider for my images:

```
// Slick slider - Responsive
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  if ($(this).width() > 1600) {
    $('.images').slick({
      dots: false,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 20, // Set at least half of all slides
      centerMode: true,
      initialSlide: 0, // Fix for centerMode with 1
      variableWidth: true,

      arrows: true,
      draggable: true,
      swipeToSlide: true,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: false,
      autoplaySpeed: 3000
    });
  }
  else {
    $('.images').unbind(slick());
  };
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize();
});
```

If I refresh the page with a viewport less than 1600px (big size only for demo purposes), the slider not become active, works great. However if I change my browser's width bigger than 1600px and change it back to less than 1600px, the slider's code stays. I used slick slider's built-in responsive flags and `unslick` feature, but the problem was the same just like here: not completely clearing up it's code.

How can I completely remove it's code without refresh, only with viewport size change?

Edit:

Strange, but looks like this unbinding completely:

```
else {
  $('.images').slick('unslick');
};
```

However the documentation suggested way is not, just partly:

```
responsive: [
  {
    breakpoint: 1600,
    settings: 'unslick'
  }
```

Edit:

Although the documentation suggested way removing it too, but not re-binding when the browser's the viewport size reaching where it should be active.

EDIT2:

THiCE's solution modified that only use timer for resize event. This way I won't get any console error on load because of `.slick('unslick');` hack:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    handleSlick();
    console.log('handleSlick() fired on load...');
  });
  var timer;
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      handleSlick();
      console.log('handleSlick() fired on resize...');
    }, 100);
    //console.log('jquery on window resize');
  });
  //handleSlick();
});
```

Comment: Maybe `$('.images').unbind(slick);` works, not sure.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not. :(

Comment: Each and every jQuery plugin may or may not implement some kind of `destroy` method. Check the docs for your plugin to see if it does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery remove plugin from element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205920/jquery-remove-plugin-from-element)

Comment: @Mathletics As I mentoined, I used `unslick`, but not completely removing the code in viewport resize, just only on reload, like in my case.

Comment: `$('.images').unbind(slick()).removeData();` also uneffecting.

Comment: Does unbinding work without resizing the viewport? i.e. from your browser's console?

Comment: @THiCE Yes, it's working when I type in `$('.images').slick('unslick');`.

Comment: And do other things happen when you resize the window? i.e. when you put `console.log('resizing...')` in the resize method?

Comment: This is the only error what I got: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null`. Seems like using `$('.images').slick('unslick');` is better than the documentation suggested way, because when the viewport reaches the size where it should be active, it's re-activating again the slider. The documentation way not.

Comment: Another errors: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unslick' of undefined`. I really don't understand this, because it's working and doing what it should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes using a setTimeout does the trick: the resize event is fired lots of times during resizing. 
If you use a timer inside the resize callback that resets and starts everytime the resize event fires, you prevent those 'double' fires.

An example, for your case:

```
  // Slick slider - Responsive
function bindSlick() {
  $('.images').slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    // etc...
  });
}

function unbindSlick() {
  $('.images').slick('unslick');
}

function handleSlick() {
  if ($(window).width() > 1600) {
    bindSlick();
  } else {
    unbindSlick(); 
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var timer;
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      handleSlick();  
    }, 100);
  });
  handleSlick();
});
```

Comment: Thank You! This one definitely produces less console errors!

Comment: With this method, I always got an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null` error message, which is usually coming up when the slider is unbinded, because `.slick('unslick');` is not the documentation way of doing this, but if I not use this hack, otherwise not will turn it on again. The console error message come up on the first start also, when only `bindSlick()` function should be active at all. The last `handleSlick()` calling causing this at the bottom. Is it possible to separate on load and resize, where timer only added for resize?